# Couldn't find basic_configs folder while setting up SolR using Bitnami

Tags: solr, sitecore8, bitnami

I have been following below article to set up Solr and stuck at Step 1
http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2016/11/part-2-sitecore-82-with-solr-62.html

I have installed solr-7.2.1-0 with latest Bitnami software ( https://bitnami.com/stack/solr ) and now looking for basic_configs folder but I couldn't find. configsets folder contains only two folder

C:\Bitnami\solr-7.2.1-0\apache-solr\server\solr\configsets

_default

sample_techproducts_configs

Now how can I complete step 1

Answer (score 0):

The installation process will create several sub-directories under the installdir (`C:\Bitnami\solr-7.2.1-0\`) directory:

- Servers and related tools: `apache2\`, `mysql\`, `postgresql\`, `apache-tomcat\`, etc.
- Languages: `php\`, `python\`, `ruby\`, `tcl\`, etc.
- Application files: `apps\phpMyAdmin\`, `apps\drupal\`, `apps\joomla\`, `apps\solr\`, etc.
- Common libraries: `common\`
- Licenses of the components included in the stack: `licenses\`

Application files are stored in the `C:\Bitnami\solr-7.2.1-0\apps\solr\htdocs` directory. The configuration file for the Apache Web server is stored in the `C:\Bitnami\solr-7.2.1-0\apps\solr\conf\` directory.